# COALESCE all fields in different tables JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, coalesce

I have 2 tables:

---

**Table 1 (with ENGLISH content):**

```
id (primary key, auto increment)
title
text
...
```

**Table 2 (with PORTUGUESE content):**

```
id (foreing Key to table 1 ID)
title
text
…
```

---

Contents example:

**Table 1 (with ENGLISH content):**

```
id: 4
title: Hello World!
text: hello world, i need you!
… : anothers fields
```

**Table 2 (with PORTUGUESE content):**

```
id: 4
title: Ola mundo
text: NULL
…: another fields with NULL values OR portuguese contents
```

---

Perfect result:

**Result:**

```
id: 4
title: Ola mundo
text: hello world, i need you!
…: another fields with english content with NULL values in portuguese table OR portuguese content if is not null values
```

---

Is the same of this question and result: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014833/sql-select-from-2-tables-with-same-column-names-only-return-column-when-not-null), but i don't know which fields are NULL and how much fields have in tables. I know the alternative table (portuguese) have same column name.
I need something like COALESCE(table1.*,table2.*), but this don't work.

```
 SELECT COALESCE(table1.*, table2.*) FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 USING(id) WHERE id = 4;
```

But in Table 2, may not have the record id "4"…

How can i get that result?

Thanks

Comment: Hey, did you figure out any way other than explicitly coalescing all columns?

Answer (score -1):

column name should be coalesced seperately

```
SELECT  a.id,COALESCE(b.title, a.title) Title,COALESCE(b.text, a.text) Text
FROM    Table1 a LEFT JOIN Table2 b
ON a.id = b.id
```

Comment: This is the problem, the table is too big, have a lot of columns. have any idea for not put the columns names in query?

Comment: No! It's because i'm creating a function, to use not only in 1 table, is for the all system…